# Что за рамка? Как его удалить с CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, веб-дизайн

Что за рамка и как его удалить (или заменить именной цвет на другое посредством JS), при указании свойства `width: 100%` для **изображения** появляется рамка, которая имеет цвет (примерно) `#c0c0c1`, искал массово не нашел данный цвет, изображение (и другие элементы) не имеют свойства `border`  Браузер Google Chrome
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь скриншот как это выглядит, и укажи в каком конкретно браузере это наблюдается. Кроме этого добавь [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и убедиться, что проблема вообще существует, а не просто у тебя где-то специально такие стили установлены

Comment: Скорее всего box-shadow

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev box-shadow-а нет (не нашел)

Comment: @Grundy скриншот добавил, браузер google chrome

Comment: имеется ввиду однопиксельная рамка? или какая? И добавь версию хрома. Воспроизводится ли это, если на странице только картинка и из стилей только `width: 100%`?

Comment: @Grundy да однопиксельная, скорее всего проблема в теге <img

Comment: @CitizenCountry, может быть какой-то стиль по умолчанию от браузера приходит

Comment: @Grundy когда пишу padding-top: 350px исчезает

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится: https://jsfiddle.net/ney6r1q7/  версия браузера Версия 66.0.3359.139 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

Comment: Поэтому нужен конкретный пример с необходимыми стилями и разметкой

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за содействие, проблему решил используя padding